# Check if 2 images are the same

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a way, where i can check if the image that is selected from my `math.random` is the same as the image my user has selected. The image the user has selected will have a `style="solid 3px #587388"` So i'm looking for a way to check if my image with `style="solid 3px #587388"` is the same as the `#winner` img. And if they are the same it should alert() Won, else lose. How can I do that?

Here is my javascript/jquery code:

```
function changeCoinBorder(obj) {
    var tCoin = document.getElementById('tCoin');
    var ctCoin = document.getElementById('ctCoin');
    tCoin.style.border = 'none';
    ctCoin.style.border = 'none';
    obj.style.border = 'solid 3px #587388';
}
var counter = 5;

setInterval(function () {
 counter--;
                if (counter >= 0) {
                    span = document.getElementById("count");
                    span.innerHTML = counter;
                }
                // Display 'counter' wherever you want to display it.
                if (counter === 0) {

                    var image = new Array();
                    image[0] = "/Content/img/ct.png";
                    image[1] = "/Content/img/teroist.png";
                    var size = image.length
                    var x = Math.floor(size * Math.random())

                    $('#winner').fadeIn().attr('src', image[x]);
                    $('#winner').addClass("WinImage");
```

And here is the html:

```
<div class="row center">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <a href="#">
            <img id="ctCoin" onclick="changeCoinBorder(this);" class="img-circle CoinImages" src="~/Content/img/ct.png" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <img id="winner" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <a href="#">
            <img id="tCoin" onclick="changeCoinBorder(this);" class="img-circle CoinImages" src="~/Content/img/teroist.png" />
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: check the src attributes of the images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

js:

```
function changeCoinBorder(obj) {

    $('.CoinImages').removeClass('selected');
    $(obj).addClass('selected');
}

function randomImg(){
    var imgs = $('.CoinImages');
    var randomOne = Math.floor(imgs.length * Math.random());
    $('#winner').fadeIn().attr('src', $(imgs[randomOne]).attr('src') );
    $('#winner').addClass("WinImage");
    if ($('#winner').attr('src') === $('.selected').attr('src')){
        alert('You win!');
    }
}
```

css:

```
.selected {border: solid 3px #587388;}
```

Check this:
https://jsfiddle.net/28mgqqk1/1/

Comment: This checks if the selected image is the same as the one that have been  random selected. You don't need to hardcode the paths in JS. Just call randomImg() whenever the timeout ends.

Comment: note you should use a CSS selector (in this case $('#ctCoin') or $('#tCoin') ). You have places with wrong selectors.

Comment: What? Can you create a codepen or jsfiddle with my js

Comment: Check lines 6, 12 and 13 of your code. You should not use setInterval without a clearInterval. Check this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGKmNj (not completedly tested)

Comment: Don't knnow if it is me that is compleatly stupid. But i doo not get what you mean? And i'm not sure how this should work

Comment: I did manage to make it "work" but it's not correct, it do not display the right result